# Mysql - error al realizar copia en remoto con mysqldump

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, mysqli, mysql-workbench, mysqldb

intento hacer una copia de una bd mysql en remoto con mysqldump y obtengo este error y la verdad no se por donde tirar.

Intento conectarme y hacer una copia de toda la base de datos.

```
C:\Windows\system32>mysqldump -h 212.XXX.XXX -P 3306 -u usuario1 -p intranet > dump.sql
Enter password: **********
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SELECT COLUMN_NAME,                       JSON_EXTRACT(HISTOGRAM,'$."number-of-buckets-specified"')                FROM information_schema.COLUMN_STATISTICS
        
WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = 'intranet' AND TABLE_NAME = 'proveedores';':
Unknown table 'COLUMN_STATISTICS' in 
information_schema (1109)
```

Gracias,

Comment: Al parecer el dump se creó en una versión moderna de MySQL (v. 8+)  y quieres restaurar en una versión más vieja ... Lo primero que hay que preguntarse es si conviene esa involución. Si puedes, deberías actualizar tu versión de MySQL. Si no puedes, entonces puedes apagar esa nueva opción que generan los dump de MySQL 8+  mediante esta bandera: `--column-statistics=0` Para más detalles revisa [esta respuesta](https://serverfault.com/a/912677) en serverfault.

Comment: Con este flag me ha funcionado. gracias por la respuesta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En la versión 8 de MySQL el comando `mysqldump` trae activada por defecto la bandera `column-statistics`, la cual es incompatible con versiones anteriores de MySQL.

Al parecer el dump de hizo en una versión MySQL 8+  y ahora intentas restaurar en una versión más vieja.

Si es posible, se recomienda actualizar tu versión de MySQL. En caso de no ser posible, puedes apagar esa opción al hacer el dump poniendo la bandera:  `--column-statistics=0`, por ejemplo:

```
C:\Windows\system32>mysqldump --column-statistics=0 -h 212.XXX.XXX -P 3306 -u usuario1 -p intranet > dump.sql
```

Para más detalles consulta [esta respuesta](https://serverfault.com/a/912677) en ServerFault.