# ¿Por qué en local se listan correctamente unos productos de una BD, y cuando lo subo a un host, ya no aparecen? (PHP y MYSQL)

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, php8

estoy haciendo una pagina con PHP y MYSQL lo que pasa es que en la sección de administracion de la página que estoy haciendo, cuando voy a ACTUALIZAR un producto en local me muestra la lista desplegable de "Tipo de Producto" con el producto previamnete escogido y los demas productos, mientras que cuando lo subo a un host, como Heroku o CleverCloud, no me lo muestra (pero los demás datos si), aclaro que al subirlo a estos servidores, obviamente utilizo una BD remota (no local), es decir, cuando voy a ACTUALIZAR un producto, me muestra todo menos "Tipo Producto". Lo mas curioso es que cuando voy a CREAR el producto, si me aparece el "Tipo Producto". Adjuntaré capturas de pantalla y luego los codigos de cada uno (actualizar.php y crear.php).
Aclaraciones

1. Estoy usando PHP 8
2. Estoy usando MySQL version 5.7.24

Adjunto Imagen de actualizar.php en LOCALHOST (AQUI SI FUNCIONA Y LISTA LOS TIPOS DE PRODUCTO DE LA BD)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora adjunto imagen de actualizar.php (PROYECTO DESPLEGADO EN HEROKU) (No muestra nada en esta sección además NO MUESTRA boton de Actualizar)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les agradeceria si me podrían ayudar, muchas gracias.

Investigando un poco y con ayuda de ustedes, al parecer es la BD, lo que yo hago es lo siguiente:
Aclaro: Uso MySQL Workbench v. 8.0.23 y uso MySQL Server 5.7.33
Uso mysqlworkbench para exportar la BD local, luego en CleverCloud (donde tengo creada la BD remota, importo esos datos)
Miren lo que me aparece antes de exportar la BD local con MySQL Workbench (tendrá algo que ver esto?):

Tengo otra pregunta, de que forma puedo EXPORTAR la BD, para que quede exactamente igual a la local?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola. Has intentado actualizar llamando la bd remota desde tu local?

Comment: Hola, sí, y haciendo eso, obtengo el mismo resultado, no se muestran los Tipos de Producto.

Comment: Vale, revisa si la estructura y datos de la bd son exactamente iguales, que la tablas tipos de producto si tiene registro. Haz la consulta utilizando phpmyadmin o navicat o la consola de sql y mira si la tabla de la bd del servidor devuelve los mismos datos que la bd local.

Comment: Creo que si tiene que ver con la BD, acabo de actualizar la publicación, y agregue esto: Investigando un poco y con ayuda de ustedes, al parecer es la BD, lo que yo hago es lo siguiente: Aclaro: Uso MySQL Workbench v. 8.0.23 y uso MySQL Server 5.7.33 Uso mysqlworkbench para exportar la BD local, luego en CleverCloud (donde tengo creada la BD remota, importo esos datos) Miren lo que me aparece antes de exportar la BD local con MySQL Workbench (tendrá algo que ver esto?) Adjunto imagen

Comment: Acabo de borrar el codigo que habia adjuntado anteriormente de crear.php y actualizar.php, veo queallí no esta el problema, el problema es el que acabe de mencionar anterioemente. Alguna ayuda?

Comment: Que dicen los logs de PHP en el servidor donde no se muestran los datos?

Comment: Creo que un dump hecho en versión 8 no tiene muchas diferencias con la versión 5, aunque todo depende de las tablas. Lo ideal sería tener todo actualizado, pero tratándose de un servidor remoto esa actualización no depende de ti. Entonces, o igualas tu versión local a la remota, o haces el dump con la versión 8 y modificas a mano aquellas cosas que sean incompatibles, que tampoco son muchas o lo indicas en el dump. [Aquí hay una respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/375937/29967) en un caso parecido al tuyo en el que lo único que fallaba era la configuración relativa a `column-statistics`

Comment: Acabo de ver el post, pero no comprendo bien que es lo que debo hacer

Comment: A lo que se refiere A. Cedano es que uses localmente la misma versión de BD que usas en servidor, es posible que si se presenten errores porque cada versión trae mejoras y cambios, sobretodo cuando hay tanta diferencia entre ambas.
En general siempre es bueno utilizar las mismas versiones de PHP y bd en desarrollo y producción para evitar esto.